# Display different navbar for logged user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I've created login/register in my app, and now i want to display different navbar based if user is logged.
I don't use redux for this project.

In App component, globally, i created state that i wanted to pass to childs, and then base on it,  display different data, so i created something like this:

```
function App() {
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!loginStatus) {
      axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/users/isUserAuth", {
        headers: {
          "x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setLoginStatus(true);
      })
    }}, [])
```

and then in my Navbar i created something like this:

```
      <NavItem style={{display: loginStatus ? "block" : "none"}}>
```

This works, but it causes loginStatus to be loaded every page refresh, every route made, so when i go to different page when user is logged, it causes 0.5s delay before NavItem will appear, because it makes request to backend on every refresh.

How can i store information that user is logged in so it wouldn't have to make API calls on every page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `localStorage` to store user logged-in information.

Comment: Is it secure method? I think it would make possible to change localStorage so it will imitate being logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize state with the local storage token and check with that state

```
const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(token)
```

Comment: Theoretically, it works. However, everyone can manually set token in their browser and they will be able to see everything that should only logged people see. If i want to verify this token i would have to make another call to API.